# Need to remove items from both a list and a dictionary of tuple value pairs at same time

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

This is very related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506857/deleting-previous-token-in-a-sentence-if-same-as-current-token-python) but I realised that my objective is much more complicated:

I have a sentence: `"Forbes Asia 200 Best Under 500 Billion 2011"`

I have tokens like:

```
oldTokens = [u'Forbes', u'Asia', u'200', u'Best', u'Under', u'500', u'Billion', u'2011']
```

And the indices of where a previous parser has figured out where there should be location or number slots:

```
numberTokenIDs =  {(7,): 2011.0, (2,): 200.0, (5,6): 500000000000.00}
locationTokenIDs = {(0, 1): u'Forbes Asia'}
```

The token IDs correspond to the index of the tokens where there are locations or numbers, the objective is to obtain a new set of tokens like:

```
newTokens = [u'Asia', u'200', u'Best', u'Under', u'500', u'2011']
```

With new number and location tokenIDs perhaps like (to avoid index out of bounds exceptions):

```
numberTokenIDs =  {(5,): 2011.0, (1,): 200.0, (4,): 500000000000.00}
locationTokenIDs = {(0,): u'Forbes Asia'}
```

Essentially I would like to go through the new reduced set of tokens, and be able to ultimately create a new sentence called:

```
"LOCATION_SLOT NUMBER_SLOT Best Under NUMBER_SLOT NUMBER_SLOT"
```

via going through the new set of tokens and replacing the correct tokenID with either "LOCATION_SLOT" or "NUMBER_SLOT". If I did this with the current set of number and location token IDs, I would get:

```
"LOCATION_SLOT LOCATION_SLOT NUMBER_SLOT Best Under NUMBER_SLOT NUMBER_SLOT NUMBER_SLOT".
```

How would I do this?

Another example is:

```
Location token IDs are:  (0, 1)
Number token IDs are:  (3, 4)
Old sampleTokens [u'United', u'Kingdom', u'USD', u'1.240', u'billion']
```

Where I want to both delete tokens and also change location and number token IDs to be able to replace the sentence like:

```
sampleTokens[numberTokenID] = "NUMBER_SLOT"
sampleTokens[locationTokenID] = "LOCATION_SLOT"
```

Such that the replaced tokens are `[u'LOCATION_SLOT', u'USD', u'NUMBER_SLOT']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a very elegant, but working solution:

```
oldTokens = [u'Forbes', u'Asia', u'200', u'Best', u'Under', u'500', u'Billion', u'2011']

numberTokenIDs =  {(7,): 2011.0, (2,): 200.0, (5,6): 500000000000.00}
locationTokenIDs = {(0, 1): u'Forbes Asia'}

newTokens = []
newnumberTokenIDs = {}
newlocationTokenIDs = {}

new_ind = 0
skip = False

for ind in range(len(oldTokens)):
    if skip:
        skip=False
        continue

    for loc_ind in locationTokenIDs.keys():
        if ind in loc_ind:
            newTokens.append(oldTokens[ind+1])
            newlocationTokenIDs[(new_ind,)] = locationTokenIDs[loc_ind]
            new_ind += 1
            if len(loc_ind) > 1: # Skip next position if there are 2 elements in a tuple
                skip = True
            break
    else:
        for num_ind in numberTokenIDs.keys():
            if ind in num_ind:
                newTokens.append(oldTokens[ind])
                newnumberTokenIDs[(new_ind,)] = numberTokenIDs[num_ind]
                new_ind += 1
                if len(num_ind) > 1:
                    skip = True
                break
        else:
            newTokens.append(oldTokens[ind])
            new_ind += 1

newTokens
Out[37]: [u'Asia', u'200', u'Best', u'Under', u'500', u'2011']

newnumberTokenIDs
Out[38]: {(1,): 200.0, (4,): 500000000000.0, (5,): 2011.0}

newlocationTokenIDs
Out[39]: {(0,): u'Forbes Asia'}
```

Comment: Hi Vadim, I am having trouble adapting this for creating a sentence like: `ForbesAsia 200 Best Under 500Billion 2011`, so I concatenate the locations and values, however I also don't want this to do so if there is no need to e.g. if the location token ID and number token ID pairs were not more than 1 in length.

Comment: The easier way is to add a list of indices for program to know at which places ID's will be concatenated. And then just add additional check: if index is in list - make a concatenation. Another solution is to modify existing schema from `[...] (2,): 200.0, (5,6): 500000000000.00` to `[...] (2,): (200.0, 0), (5,6): (500000000000.00, 1)`.

Comment: Understood. Should I ask a separate question on SO on this or could you possibly put this as a second version of your answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917962/create-new-tokens-and-tuples-from-existing-ones-based-on-conditions