# Create new tokens and tuples from existing ones based on conditions

Tags: python, loops, tuples, token, tokenize

This is very related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509239/need-to-remove-items-from-both-a-list-and-a-dictionary-of-tuple-value-pairs-at-s/38512276?noredirect=1#comment65178650_38512276) but I am having difficulties adapting for my use case.

I have a sentence: `"Forbes Asia 200 Best Under 500 Billion 2011"`

I have tokens like:

```
oldTokens = [u'Forbes', u'Asia', u'200', u'Best', u'Under', u'500', u'Billion', u'2011']
```

And the indices of where a previous parser has figured out where there should be location or number slots:

```
numberTokenIDs =  {(7,): 2011.0, (2,): 200.0, (5,6): 500000000000.00}
locationTokenIDs = {(0, 1): u'Forbes Asia'}
```

The token IDs correspond to the index of the tokens where there are locations or numbers, the objective is to obtain a new set of tokens like:

```
newTokens = [u'ForbesAsia', u'200', u'Best', u'Under', u'500Billion', u'2011']
```

With new number and location tokenIDs perhaps like (to avoid index out of bounds exceptions):

```
numberTokenIDs =  {(5,): 2011.0, (1,): 200.0, (4,): 500000000000.00}
locationTokenIDs = {(0,): u'Forbes Asia'}
```

Essentially I would like to go through the new reduced set of tokens, and be able to ultimately create a new sentence called:

`"LOCATION_SLOT NUMBER_SLOT Best Under NUMBER_SLOT NUMBER_SLOT"`

via going through the new set of tokens and replacing the correct tokenID with either `LOCATION_SLOT` or `NUMBER_SLOT`. If I did this with the current set of number and location token IDs, I would get:

`"LOCATION_SLOT LOCATION_SLOT NUMBER_SLOT Best Under NUMBER_SLOT NUMBER_SLOT NUMBER_SLOT".`

How would I do this?

Another example is:

```
Location token IDs are:  (0, 1)
Number token IDs are:  (3, 4)
```

Old sampleTokens `[u'United', u'Kingdom', u'USD', u'1.240', u'billion']`

Where I want to both delete tokens and also change location and number token IDs to be able to replace the sentence like:

```
sampleTokens[numberTokenID] = "NUMBER_SLOT"
sampleTokens[locationTokenID] = "LOCATION_SLOT"
```

Such that the replaced tokens are `[u'LOCATION_SLOT', u'USD', u'NUMBER_SLOT']`

Note, the concatenation should concatenate all the values in the tuple if there are more than one (also the tuple could also contain >2 elements e.g. `The United States of America`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (if I understood correctly):

```
token_by_index = dict(enumerate(oldTokens))
groups = numberTokenIDs.keys() + locationTokenIDs.keys()
for group in groups:
    token_by_index[group[0]] = ''.join(token_by_index.pop(index)
                                       for index in group)
newTokens = [token for _, token in sorted(token_by_index.items(),
                                          key=lambda (index, _): index)]
```

to find the new token ids:

```
new_index_by_token = dict(map(lambda (i, t): (t, i), enumerate(newTokens))
numberTokenIDs = {(new_index_by_token[token_by_index[group[0]]],): value
                  for group, value in numberTokenIDs.items()}
locationTokenIDs = {(new_index_by_token[token_by_index[group[0]]],): value
                    for group, value in locationTokenIDs.items()}
```

Comment: How do I return the new number and location tokenIDs to match these new tokens? e.g. `numberTokenIDs =  {(5,): 2011.0, (1,): 200.0, (4,): 500000000000.00}`